# What does "don’t get us started on" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

The complete sentense is "On average, the more public member functions are, the harder it is to find bugs — and please don’t **get us started on** the complexities of debugging classes with public data."

I've found some similar phrases, but they don't fit in this context:

- start on - to begin dealing with someone or something (but then why "started on"?)
- get smb to do smth
- don't get me started - Used to attempt to avoid or abbreviate a discussion that speaker or hearer may wish to avoid.

Comment: Relevant: https://screen.yahoo.com/jeannie-darcy-1-000000574.html

Comment: Found the quote: https://books.google.ca/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA323&lpg=PA323&dq=%22On+average,+the+more+public+member+functions+are,+the+harder+it+is+to+find+bugs+%E2%80%94+and+please+don%27t+get+us+started+on+the+complexities+of+debugging+classes+with+public+data.%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third phrase that you have ruled out is in fact what this expression means. In the sentence you are asking about, the speaker is apparently responding to a question about how hard it is to find bugs given a particular circumstance, and adding an incidental comment that it is harder still given another particular circumstance. This is of course a rhetorical device, and does not mean he literally is attempting to avoid additional discussion. The speaker is saying something equivalent to, if you think it's hard given X, you should see how hard it is given Y.